# image ontop of an image in php

Tags: php, image

Here is a link to the page http://www.true-gamerz.net/test2.php

if you look at the image, The rank image is transpent but it dose not show it on the screen
dose anyone know why this  is happen?

Here is the code

```
 <?  

 header('content-type: image/png');  

 $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('images/ranks/ranks_18.png');  
 $watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);  
 $watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);  
 $image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);  
 $image = imagecreatefrompng("images/card/test.png");  
 $size = getimagesize("images/card/test.png");  
 $dest_x = $watermark_width;  
 $dest_y = $watermark_height;  
 imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, 289, 4, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);  
 imagepng($image);  

 imagedestroy($image);  
 imagedestroy($watermark);  
 ?>
```

Comment: You've made it? Let us know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imagecopymerge does not support alpha channel

Read this for workaround:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php#92787